# Find the domain of $F(a)= \int_{0}^{\infty}e^{a\sqrt{y}}dy$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus

Find the domain of $F(a)=  \int_{0}^{\infty}e^{a\sqrt{y}}dy$

In the solution we did $a <0$ and $a\geq0$.

For $a \geq 0 $, we have: $e^{a\sqrt{y}} \geq 1 \implies F(a) = \infty$

However, I do not understand, why does it imply infinity. If we look at for substitution $t = a\sqrt{y}$, we get: $$\frac{2}{a^2}(te^t - \int e^tdt)$$ with bounds from $0$ to $\infty$. (we get undefined since, $\infty-\infty$ is undefined)

Can somebody explain the conclusion in line 3.

Also another question would be, why do we have to $a<0$ and $a\geq 0$ ?

Comment: If $a>0$, then $e^{a\sqrt y}\geq 1$ for all $y\geq 0$.

Comment: Be careful with indefinite integrals. You get positive infinity because we are integrating a number at least $1$ over an infinite domain, so the integral will be greater than $\int_0^\infty 1dx=\infty$ because the integral of a constant function is that constant times the length of the interval, which is here $\infty$. The integral will only converge for $a\lt 0$. I strongly suggest you plot some graphs on Desmos to get a feel for it if none of this is obvious.

Comment: @FShrike So every time we have something more than or equal to one under the integral that goes to infinity, we have the whole integral equal to infinity?

Comment: @FShrike However I still dont understand how in solutions the domain is $(-\infty, 0)$

Comment: As we discussed, $F(0)=\int_0^\infty1dx$=\infty$ so $F$ is undefined at $a=0$ as a real function, and is in fact undefined as a real function for $a\ge0$. For any $a\lt0$, the integral will converge (prove it!), $F$ will output a real number and $F$ will be defined. The set $a\lt0$ is the same as the set $(-\infty,0)$, and notice the curved parentheses - we do *not* include $0$ in the domain of $F$

Comment: If $a<0,$ then $$e^{-a\sqrt y}\geq 1+\frac{a^4y^2}{4!}.$$

Comment: @FShrike Can you please edit your comment in latex ?

Comment: My comment is not editable after such time has passed. It is also already in MathJax. What do you want? Your question has been sufficiently answered in the comments, so you should specify for what else you’d like to know

Comment: @FShrike Does the upper bound of integral become $-\infty$ or does the lower bound?
Why so ?

Comment: Ah. I think you have confused domain and codomain/range. The domain is the set on which the function is define: here, $(-\infty,0)$ is the set on which $F$ is defined, because it converges there, and diverges (not defined as a real function) everywhere else. The **codomain** of $F$ is a different question, to which the answer is $(0,\infty)$, as, if I’m not mistaken, that is the range of outputs for this integral when $a$ is negative

Comment: In fact, I’ll leave it as an exercise for you (do you know about the Gamma function?) to show that, when $a\lt0$, $F(a)=\frac{2}{a^2}$. You can then more clearly see that the *codomain* is $(0,\infty)$ - but remember the integral only converges for negative $a$, so the *domain* is $(-\infty,0)$.

Comment: @FShrike I understand now